# Side brackets next to a vector in Typst

Tags: typst

Is there a way to add brackets next to a vector in typst?

[image]

This post explains how to do it in Latex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331506/how-to-put-more-than-one-side-braces-for-a-vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `#stack()` function, similar to the LaTeX solution, and put it next to your vector. You can then use `#lr()` to scale a single closing `}` delimiter. Depending on the content of your vector, you will have to play around with the sizes. It is possible to measure the sizes needed with the `#measure()` function but it might be more prone to break.

#### Manual solution:

```
$
bold(upright(x)) = vec(x_1, dots.v, x_(n_1), x_(n_1 + 1), dots.v, x_n)
#stack(dir: ttb, spacing: 1em, $ lr(}, size: #350%) n_1$, $ lr(}, size: #350%) n_2$)
$
```

#### Automated (`measure`) solution:

```
#let side-bracket(inp, br1, br2) = style(styles => {
  let half-height = measure(inp, styles).height / 2
  $
  inp
  #stack(dir: ttb, spacing: 1em, $ lr(}, size: #half-height) #br1$, $ lr(}, size: #half-height) #br2$)
  $
}) 

#side-bracket($ bold(upright(x)) = vec(x_1, dots.v, x_(n_1), x_(n_1 + 1), dots.v, x_n) $, $n_1$, $n_2$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is quite easy with Typst:

```
$ vec(x_1, dots.v, x_n,
   x_(n+1), dots.v,
   delim: "{"
  ) 
  #stack(
    $ lr(} #v(3em)) n_1 $,
    0.5em,
    $ lr(} #v(2em)) n_2 $
  )
 $
```

Will produce approximately this result: [(rendered by Discord bot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuIoZ.png) (can't insert images directly, my first answer there).

The idea is roughly the same as in LaTeX, using `stack` near the vector with appropriate spacing. Instead of lots of new lines you can use vertical spacing (`#v(3em)` is roughly the same as "three lines"). `lr` there is used to stretch the left delimiter (`}`) to all height of `#v(...)`, and `n` is placed in it's center by default.

It is quite easy to modify that example to whatever you want, the idea is pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks! This solution almost worked for me, but the vector and the brackets where very far apart and it added an equation number for each line.